# OpenCV unknown layer type running darknet detect

Tags: opencv, runtime-error, yolo

I'm trying to switch from using Yolo v2 to Yolo v3 and can't get the detection to work. I'm getting the error

```
OpenCV Error: Parsing error (Unknown layer type: shortcut) in ReadDarknetFromCfgFile
```

Anybody know how I can fix this? Using a cfg file from Yolo v2 works fine.

Comment: YoloV3 support has just been added in [PR#11322](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/11322) and merged in Opencv 3.4 branch. It should be soon added also in master branch.

Comment: So upgrade your opencv version - `pip install --upgrade opencv-python`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Support for running YOLOv3 has been added to OpenCV master branch (3.4.3).

You should be able to use [YOLOv3 config](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolov3.cfg) and [weights](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) with OpenCV DNN module to perform object detection.

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNet(args.weights, args.config)

blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, scale, (416,416), (0,0,0), True, crop=False)

net.setInput(blob)

outs = net.forward(get_output_layers(net))
```

Full code [here](https://github.com/arunponnusamy/object-detection-opencv/blob/master/yolo_opencv.py).

Have a look at the [object detection](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/object_detection.py) example in the samples/dnn directory on OpenCV's [github repo](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/).

This [blog post](http://www.arunponnusamy.com/yolo-object-detection-opencv-python.html) (written by me) explains in detail about performing object detection with pre-trained YOLOv3 weights on [COCO dataset](http://cocodataset.org) to detect [80 common objects](https://github.com/arunponnusamy/object-detection-opencv/blob/master/yolov3.txt) in context.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please just note if you want to promote or recommend your own product/blog, there are some [guidelines in place](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) for doing so. Following them will help you avoid giving the impression that you're spamming. Could you please edit to explicitly state your affiliation? Thanks. (If you're not actually affiliated, it may be worth mentioning that as well.)

Comment: Thanks @Filnor for pointing out. I have explicitly stated my affiliation. The blog post genuinely explains the solution in detail. If needed I can remove the link.

Comment: No, you don't need to remove the link, your posts looks fine now.