# OpenCV(3.4.1-dev) Errors while running video object detection

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-16.04, object-detection, yolo

I'm working on a project that I found online (Yolo Object Detection with OpenCV, one of Pyimageresearch projects). So, I downloaded the whole code and saved it in the Downloads folder as it was recommended the run the cmd line script:

```
python /home/ubuntu/Downloads/yolo-object-detection/yolo_video.py \
> --input /home/ubuntu/Downloads/yolo-object-detection/videos/WS-1sec.mp4 \
> --output /home/ubuntu/Downloads/yolo-object-detection/output/WS-1sec.avi \
> --yolo /home/ubuntu/Downloads/yolo-object-detection/yolo-coco
```

but the output was:

```
[INFO] loading YOLO from disk...
OpenCV(3.4.1-dev) Error: Parsing error (Unknown layer type: shortcut) in ReadDarknetFromCfgFile, file /home/ubuntu/src/opencv/modules/dnn/src/darknet/darknet_io.cpp, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/yolo-object-detection/yolo_video.py", line 42, in <module>
    net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(configPath, weightsPath)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1-dev) /home/ubuntu/src/opencv/modules/dnn/src/darknet/darknet_io.cpp:503: error: (-212) Unknown layer type: shortcut in function ReadDarknetFromCfgFile
```

I'm running the same exact version of OpenCV 3.4.1 on another machine and it worked there! This time I'm working on the Tetson TX2 but didn't rum!

Link to original project is [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/11/12/yolo-object-detection-with-opencv/).

Any idea why these error occurs please!?

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the project you're working on?

Comment: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/11/12/yolo-object-detection-with-opencv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have the wrong OpenCV version. Check this answer:

[OpenCV unknown layer type running darknet detect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925933/opencv-unknown-layer-type-running-darknet-detect)

*"Support for running YOLOv3 has been added to OpenCV master branch (3.4.3)."*

Comment: Thanks for your response Guilheme, I'm running the same exact version of OpenCV 3.4.1 on another machine and it worked there! This time I'm working on the Tetson TX2 but didn't rum! Also, I already went through this solution and tried to update the Yolov3.conf file with the new code  but still didn't work!

Comment: I have worked with Jetson TX2 myself and versioning can be tricky. Be sure that the OpenCV python version is the same as the built from source one (it might be the case). Another link that supports my hypothesis: https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/issues/112

Comment: And at the pyimagesearch post itself Adam says: _"I cannot stress this enough: you’ll need at least OpenCV **3.4.2** to run this code as it has the updated dnn  module required to load YOLO."_

Comment: Thanks Guilheme, You are right! I just confused and mixed up between versions of the OpenCvs I have.