# Unknown layer type: shortcut in function cv::dnn::darknet::ReadDarknetFromCfgFile

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to implement yolov3 using opencv, I am working with jupterlab, python 3.7.3, and opencv 3.4.1

```
import numpy as np
import os
# Load Yolo 
weightsPath = os.path.sep.join(['yolo', "yolov3.weights"])
configPath = os.path.sep.join(['yolo', "yolov3.cfg"])

print("[INFO] loading YOLO from disk...")
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(configPath, weightsPath)
classes = []
with open("coco.names", "r") as f:
    classes = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
output_layers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(classes), 3))
```

and it is returning this error:

`error: OpenCV(3.4.1) C:\Miniconda3\conda-bld\opencv-suite_1533128839831\work\modules\dnn\src\darknet\darknet_io.cpp:503: error: (-212) Unknown layer type: shortcut in function cv::dnn::darknet::ReadDarknetFromCfgFile`

**I searched online but couldn't find a clue, please help!**

Comment: Could you try updating your OpenCV version to at least v3.4.3? There were some fixes for DNN modules.

Comment: can you add the content of yolov3.cfg? Can you try with newer opencv version? Looks like the "shortcut" layer type isnt supported in your version.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925933/opencv-unknown-layer-type-running-darknet-detect

Comment: I tried updating OpenCV but there is a problem on anaconda, it gave me the message that all requirements are already installed, but still have opencv v3.4.1. However, I replaced yolov3 with yolov2 and it worked. Thank you for clarification.